# Can we find a function which vanish at the decimals of the Liouville's constant?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

Thinking to Liouville's constant I was hoping If we can find with the decimal of the famous constant a function wich vanish at these decimals .

I found currently a very simple function wich is :

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(10^{-1!}-x\right)\left(10^{-2!}-x\right)\left(10^{-3!}-x\right)...$$

Can we find a more "sophisticated" example ?Is there bigger maths here ?

Thanks in advance .

Edit : By more "sophisticated" I mean we cannot use this "canonical" function just in adding or composing or multiplying this function with another . "Un dépaysement soudain" as Grothedieck could wrote is needed.

Comment: Do you mean a function with roots at $10^{-n!}$ for every positive integer $n$ and no other roots ?

Comment: @Peter Not necessarly and not the same example with power .I think this question is not innocent and there is something deeper but it's just a simple guess.

Comment: I have no idea what you could be asking for. "Un depaysement soudain" means, if my French is still any good, "a sudden change of scenery." What does that mean here? And also, why can I not use this function?

Comment: The function you have defined is an infinite product that does not converge anywhere except $x=-1$. In general, there will not be a "nice" function that has zeros at every $10^{-n!}$; more precisely, there is no such real analytic function that's defined at $x=0$, since the zeros of a real analytic function cannot have an accumulation point in the function's domain.

Comment: "which", not "wich"

Comment: one can cheat and find a function that is analytic on $\mathbb C^*$ by finding an entire $g(z)$ with zeroes at $10^{n!}$ and doing $f(z)=g(1/z)$

Comment: @GregMartin Have you some hint for me to show it or can you make an answer can I learn ?